# Node.js e PHP no mesmo servidor

Tags: php, node.js, centos, plesk

Tenho um servidor dedicado CentOS 6.5 com o Painel Plesk 12 instalado, com vários sites em php. Gostaria de desenvolver um chat com node.js e integra-lo com alguns sites feitos em php. Só que esse chat precisa recuperar algumas informações do usuário que está logado Ex.: O usuário só pode acessar o chat se estiver logado. Qual seria a melhor maneira de integrar as duas coisas PHP + Node.js?

**Solução:**

Segui a sugestão do Lauro Moraes nessa pergunta: Integrar aplicação nodejs a site php em servidores distintos?, e fiz o que o Guilherme me sugeriu. O cliente se loga no site PHP, os dados da sessão são salvos no banco de dados no caso eu usei o Redis. Na parte do php eu solicito ao Node.js por meio do socket.io enviando o cookie com o id da sessão. No Node.js eu pego esse id da sessão, consulto no banco de dados do Redis e libero o acesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente você está querendo construir uma arquitetura com SSO (Single sign-on). O SSO é definido como um único ponto de entrada, ou seja, você necessita se autenticar uma única vez. Isso permite acesso automático a diversos módulos de um sistema, sem a necessidade de digitar seu login e senha em cada módulo.

Para implementar o SSO, é preciso construir uma arquitetura para realizar essa comunicação entre sistemas diferentes. No seu caso, há uma abordagem relativamente simples para sua pergunta: guardar as informações no estado de sessão com o PHP em um banco de dados, e ler, com o Node.js, o cookie de sessão e verificá-lo no banco de dados para se certificar que o usuário está logado.

Existem outras soluções parecidas como [o uso de memcache no Node.js](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/php-nodejs-session-share-memcache/), mas todas possuem uma implementação relativamente grande, que não seria recomendado colocar aqui (ocuparia muito espaço da tela).

### Referências

[O que é o Single Sign-On](https://duvidas.terra.com.br/duvidas/3301/o-que-e-o-single-sign-on)
[Sharing data between php and node.js via cookie securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879132/sharing-data-between-php-and-node-js-via-cookie-securely)

Comment: Guilherme dá para colocar exemplos de código para resolver o problema?

Comment: É que a solução não é lá muito pequena. Existem alguns artigos sobre [como guardar as sessões no banco de dados em PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Storing-PHP-Sessions-in-a-Database/), por exemplo, que são um pouco extensos.